# How can I return an array or vector or map without creating a temporary variable for it in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, return

In java, an array can be returned with `return new int[] {1,2,3}` . In C++ I'm used to make an array(say temp) first, then store `1,2,3` in it and then, return it with `return temp`. How can I  return `{1,2,3}` without using temp. Can I just return vector or map similarly(instead of an array) without a temporary variable to store them in C++? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Because of mandatory copy elision, extra copies from returning from a function are rarely a problem in modern C++.

Comment: Did you try `return {1,2,3};`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There is no mandatory copy elision for `return temp`

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about copy-elision, but rather how to avoid temporary *variables* inside the function.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are very different from what you get in other modern languages because of C++'s  derivation from C, and when they branched, C was designed to solve different problems like kilohertz-speed computers with bytes of RAM. You never wanted to copy an array in those days, so you couldn't. Today, you usually don't want an array, you want [a library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Returning a std::vector provides yet another benefit ... on Linux 20.04, using g++ v9.3.0, the sizeof a vector is 24 bytes, regardless of content type, and regardless number of elements in the vector.  The container keeps all the data in dynamic memory.  The function can simply return the temp variable, "std::vector<T> temp;" which is always a trivial size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really return a plain array. Plain arrays decays to pointers (to their first element) and what you return is such a pointer. This won't work because the life-time of the array ends when the function ends, and the pointer will immediately become invalid.

But you can easily return a `std::array` or `std::vector` object just like want:

```
std::vector<int> foo()
{
    return { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same with std::map?

Comment: @AbinashDash You can do this with any standard container. And non-standard container as well, if they implement the correct constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just write a function like this:

```
std::vector<int> f() 
{
  return {1,2,3};
}
```

which returns a `vector` without creating a temporary.

From c++17, you could also write:

```
auto f() {
  return std::vector {1,2,3};  // int is deduced
}
```

Comment: Where can I get more info about this topic (like what's going on inside or where can we apply this?) ? Any ref docs to explore more on this?

Comment: @AbinashDash I suggest this (https://www.learncpp.com/), which I am looking at.